# How can I insert Javascript right before the body in my custom theme?

Tags: 7, javascript

[image: screenshot]

I want to make the same jquery menu in my custom drupal theme but ***I could not insert the inline script*** right before the body.

I made a separate JavaScript file, and added to my custom .info file, but this is not the right way to insert inline JavaScript, obviously.

[image: screenshot]

This is my info file.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where does the markup for the menus come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this helps but I had a similar problem before. I solved it by using the `jQuery` syntax instead of the `$`, like so:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#a a').css({'background-position','-20px 55px'});
    // and so on
});
```

You could load your js file by calling the `drupal_add_js()` in the `THEME_preprocess_page()` hook in your template.php file.

Comment: Thx a lot @Krister Andersson, I made it with drupal_add_js().      `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'kei2').'/menuInlineJS.js', 'theme'); `

Comment: @wallace740 Are you sure this is adding the code inline?

Comment: @Andy - To add it inline you could specify 'inline' as the second parameter to `drupal_add_js()`

Comment: @KristerAndersson I know - I was just surprised that the OP was asking specifically how to do it inline, and then posted a solution that wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
```

Try with this
refer here for more details : http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to insert the JavaScript code right after the `<body>` tag, you can add the following code right after the `<body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($) {
    $(function () {
      $('#a a') // ...
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I suspect you are asking because a dialog box opens reporting a warning. That is because you should wrap the code using the jQuery library with `(function ($) { /* Your code. */ })(jQuery);` as it is done with any JavaScript file used from Drupal, such as batch.js.

```
(function ($) {

/**
 * Attaches the batch behavior to progress bars.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.batch = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#progress', context).once('batch', function () {
      var holder = $(this);

      // Success: redirect to the summary.
      var updateCallback = function (progress, status, pb) {
        if (progress == 100) {
          pb.stopMonitoring();
          window.location = settings.batch.uri + '&op=finished';
        }
      };

      var errorCallback = function (pb) {
        holder.prepend($('<p class="error"></p>').html(settings.batch.errorMessage));
        $('#wait').hide();
      };

      var progress = new Drupal.progressBar('updateprogress', updateCallback, 'POST', errorCallback);
      progress.setProgress(-1, settings.batch.initMessage);
      holder.append(progress.element);
      progress.startMonitoring(settings.batch.uri + '&op=do', 10);
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Putting the JavaScript code inlined right after the `<body>` tag, inlined inside the `<head>` tag, or in a file doesn't normally makes any difference, especially if all the code does is waiting for the DOM being loaded, and calls one or more jQuery functions, as in your case.